# Unauthorised (instead of my custom message) returned when user uses wrong credentials to authenticate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js

I am using passport.js to authenticate a user upon login in my node js app. So I am also using express framework and mongo db.

This is my route:

```
router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local'),
    function(req, res, err) {
        var query = {
            'username': req.user.username
        };
        var update = {
            last_login_date: Date.now()
        };
        var options = {
            new: true
        };
        User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                res.json('Welcome ' + req.user.username);
            }
        });
    });
```

And this is my passport code:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'User does not exist'
                });
            }

            User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (isMatch) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Invalid password'
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }));
```

So, when a user logs in using the correct credentials, I get the following printed out:

```
Welcome 'username'
```

---

However, in the following scenarios, my code does not print out custom messages:

Password      Username         Response           Should be:
INCORRECT     CORRECT          Unauthorized       Invalid password
CORRECT       INCORRECT        Unauthorized       User does not exist
INCORRECT     INCORRECT        Unauthorized       User does not exist

According to passport.js documentation:

> By default, if authentication fails, Passport will respond with a 401
>   Unauthorized status, and any additional route handlers will not be
>   invoked.

However, you can have your own custom callback messages instead of Unauthorized, which does not seem to work for me.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: function(req, res, err) this err might be overriding function(err, user) this one . change it to something else like err1

Comment: Im afraid same issue

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same issue.